# Use XmlDocument to get XML data in Metro apps

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, xmldocument

It seems silly for someone.
I working on this last few days still I am not yet get success.
I working for Windows Store application using c#.
I am trying to parse the XMl file from local.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<package version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="BookId">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
   <dc:title>Cinderella; Or The Little Glass Slipper</dc:title>
   <dc:creator>Anonymous</dc:creator>
   <dc:date>2009-10-14</dc:date>
   <dc:subject>Youth</dc:subject>
   <dc:language>en</dc:language>
   <dc:publisher>Web Books Publishing</dc:publisher>
   <dc:identifier id="BookId">web-books-154</dc:identifier>
 </metadata>
 <manifest>
     <item id="ncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml" />
     <item id="W000Title" href="000Title.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
     <item id="W01MB154" href="01MB154.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
     <item id="WTOC" href="TOC.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item id="style" href="style.css" media-type="text/css" />
    <item id="cover" href="cover.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg11" href="images/img11.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg12" href="images/img12.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg2" href="images/img2.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg4" href="images/img4.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg6" href="images/img6.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg7" href="images/img7.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="Wimg9" href="images/img9.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
 </manifest>
  <spine toc="ncx">
    <itemref idref="W000Title" />
    <itemref idref="W01MB154" />
 </spine>
</package>
```

From the above Xml file I want href Values in 
For this I am `XmlDocument()`. Here is my c# Code.

```
XmlNodeList itemref = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("itemref");
            foreach (XmlElement idref in itemref)
            {
                if (idref.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlAttribute Str1 = idref.GetAttributeNode("idref");
                    ids1list.Add(Str1.Value); //List
          }
            }
XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("item");
           foreach (XmlElement item in itemNodes)
            {
                    XmlAttribute str2 = item.GetAttributeNode("id");
                    ids2list.Add(str2.value);
                    XmlAttribute str3 = item.GetAttributeNode("href");
                    ids3list.Add(str3.value);
             }
            var resut = ids1list.Intersect(ids2list).ToList();
```

In the *resut list* I have the values of **id** elements. I want next value which is **href** using **id value**,
Is there any way to get next element value,.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XmlDocument to Retrieve values in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396655/using-xmldocument-to-retrieve-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, It may Dupplicate. But People thought It is Console Or windows Application,That's why the question is going in other way, The `XmlDocument()` is varies in Store application.
Thanks

Comment: You can _edit_ a question (and the tags).

Comment: @HenkHolterman ha,OK. What I thought is the namesapce of  `XmlDocument()` is same for all .net platforms before I posted my first question. You suggesting me to Change my First question.. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by following code,

```
            XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("item");
            if (itemNodes.Count > 0)
            {
               foreach (XmlElement node in itemNodes)
               {
                 ids3list.Add(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
               }
            }
```

Comment: I am getting this error **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'**
Plz see this [http://sdrv.ms/15an5Tq ]
Why bcz `XmlDocument()` is different in Windows store apps,.

Comment: Let me know can u write, itemNodes[0].Attributes["href"].Value

Comment: Try to write : XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("item");
            if (itemNodes.Count > 0)
            {ids3list.Add(itemNodes[0].Attributes["href"].Value)
            } if it shows no error please knock me

Comment: No,I tried these things,It won't work.
Thanks you for considering my question.

Comment: You can look at the classes available for Windows Store apps in Visual Studio's Object Browser (on the View menu).

If you search for "XmlNode" it will bring you to Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList which should get you to the right area for everything you need.

Comment: may be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868253.aspx will help

Comment: try the new solution i wirte in the answer section @kumar or you can visit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/65cffae7-a264-43a8-82e3-aa506d005ad3/get-element-values-from-xml-in-c there is a solution exist.

Comment: I tried It won't work, 
That msdn solution solution is non-predictable.
I am trying use `XDocument` or any thing else

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Store XmlDocument to read / write an attribute value:

```
XmlAttribute attr = (XmlAttribute)attrColl.GetNamedItem("href");
attr.Value = "images/img11.jpg";
or
string val = attr.Value;
```

[MSDN: XmlDocument.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f285y48(v=vs.110).aspx)