# c# XMLDocument values to List/Array

Tags: c#, xml

I know there are a lot of the same questions but I can't crack this one.
I have an XMLDocument and I need to iterate through the values.

```
        <InfoResponse xmlns="">
           <ns1:ID xmlns:ns1="http://www.svt.si/evlog">2399237000/03-069-1-41/2023</ns1:ID>
           <ns1:ID xmlns:ns1="http://www.svt.si/evlog">2399237000/03-069-1-42/2023</ns1:ID>
        </InfoResponse>
```

I have tried with IEnumerable, XmlNodelist, List and always get the same result.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(response);

String test = xmlDocument.InnerText;
```

returns

```
2399237000/03-069-1-41/20232399237000/03-069-1-42/2023
```

I need an array or a list so I can iterate through and perform next action.

I tried the suggested solutions [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)
but the result is the same. I think the problem is that they all have the same node name/id.

Edit
As suggested the namespace ns1 might not be defined so here is the whole string response I get:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <soap:Body>
        <InfoResponse xmlns="">
            <ns1:ID xmlns:ns1="http://www.svt.si/evlog">2399237000/03-069-1-41/2023</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:ID xmlns:ns1="http://www.svt.si/evlog">2399237000/03-069-1-42/2023</ns1:ID>
        </InfoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is the response ok?

I'm adding the suggested solution with the foreach - at this point I'm not sure, if I'm doing it correctly:

```
string[] strArray = XElement.Parse(response)
                        .Elements()
                        .Select(d => d.Value)
                        .ToArray();

foreach (string xn in strArray)
{
    Logger.LogInfo("ID: " + xn);
}
```

This now returns 2 elements - One empty and the other has both values.

**Edit2**

```
        string[] strArray = XElement.Parse(soapResponse)
                                    .Descendants("InfoResponse")
                                    .Elements()
                                    .Select(d => d.Value)
                                    .ToArray();
```

returns an empty array..

Comment: XML is not valid since the namespace ns1 is not defined.

Comment: This is the soap response without envelope and header. How should the ns1 be defined?

Comment: @jdweng How should the ns1 be defined?

Comment: The ns1 must be in the file.  To parse you probably need the envelope and header so the namespace is defined.  Most libraries will give exceptions without the namespace.  Post code with Envelope and Header and will give a solution.

Comment: You asked for and retrieved a string. Why would you expect `InnerText` to be an array or list? [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-7.0#navigate-the-document-tree) has examples of navigating the tree. That seems like a good start...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using XmlDocument to Retrieve values in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396655/using-xmldocument-to-retrieve-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You get this envelope from some service, right? Does this service provide its description in the form of a wsdl? If so, generate a set of C# classes based on it and work with them. Then forget about raw XML and enjoy strict typing.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes there is a wsdl. It builds the classes,.. The problem is that it fails on SSL handshake. There seems to be a problem with the server certificate. So we decided on raw approach - time pressure :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't expect an array out of what I wrote. I tried all options I found on stack and elswhere - just didn't have a working code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is always easier to use Linq

```
string[] test = XElement.Parse(response)
                            .Descendants("InfoResponse")
                            .Elements()
                            .Select(d => d.Value)
                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: The code will not work without defining the namespace.

Comment: @jdweng I never post untested code

Comment: @jdweng - I have also tested this code and can confirm it works. The `Elements()` method doesn't care about namespace.

Comment: @Serge I tried both and both add 2 items, but one is empty and the second one has both values.. I edited my question and added your solution.

Comment: @user805528 You have significantly changed your xml. See my update

Comment: @Serge I tried your solution: XElement.Parse(soapResponse).Descendants("InfoResponse").Elements().Select(d => d.Value) <- QuickWatch says Enumeration yielded not results. ToArray just gives an empty array.

Comment: @user805528 All my code is tested.  I don't know how you use quickwatch

Comment: What am I doing wrong? [Fiddle](https://shorturl.at/lDKO2)

Comment: @user805528 Are you wearing glasses? Your code is completely different from mine.